# Display text and image inside 'div'

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an image inside a div and text below the image. If I set image property float: left, the text is displayed in the same line. I want to display the text in the next line in the center.

```css
.group1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='group1'>
  <p> <span> <img src='img1.png'> </span>
  </p>
  <p> <span class='title'> First </span>
  </p>
  <p> <span> second </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

How to display the text 'First' in the next line in the center?
The image should be present in the left side of the div

Comment: if you know the layout is breaking because of `float: left`, then why are you using it? if you are trying to get the image to left align, use `display: block` instead of `float: left`.

Comment: I want to display the image first and text in the next line.

Comment: I used display:block  and clear:both,  the text is displayed in the next line :)

Answer (score 3):

You should not forget to clear the float when you use it. You may google about clearfix. In most case we can just use `overflow:hidden;` to the parent.

```css
.group1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
.group1 > p:first-child{
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class='group1'>
  <p> <span> <img src='img1.png'> </span>
  </p>
  <p> <span class='title'> First </span>
  </p>
  <p> <span> second </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: My personal opinion: I don't recommend `overflow: hidden` to any dev. because it is a quick fix which is hackish. I suggest to go with clearfix as you mentioned.

Comment: So, I have mentioned about clearfix. The OP should do a research about that. Here we're to help.

Comment: And if the height is not set, `overflow:hidden;` is my personal choice. A quick fix and works better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:block` so that your span elements are treated like block elements. Also, use `clear:both` so that your elements will not be affected by the floated elements.

```
 .title {
font-size: 14px;
display:block;
clear:both;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uwwh06m6/)**

Comment: p is already a block element, why span needed to set block-level element? It hampers the layout.

Comment: thanks. the image is displayed first and the text is displayed in the next line.

Comment: i will remove the span.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal I know but the `<p>` that contains `.title` is not cleared from the float. The proper way would be to clear the `<p>` first but he gave the `span` the class and the styling.

Comment: I gave the styling inside the span.

Answer (score 1):

set `p` width to 100% float:left

```css
.group1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.group1 p {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.group1 img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='group1'>
  <p> <span> <img src='http://placeimg.com/50/50/any'/> </span>

  </p>
  <p> <span class='title'> First </span>

  </p>
  <p> <span> second </span>

  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One `<br/>` to rule them all.

Try this.

```css
.group1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='group1'>
  <p> <span> <img src='img1.png'> </span>
  </p>
  <br/>
  <p> <span class='title'> First </span>
  </p>
  <p> <span> second </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `<br />` is not good because in big projects, if you use `br`, you can't trace a frontend issue easily.

Comment: @Ajaii What is your reason ?

Comment: for big projects, we have to include break in many places. From other answers, display:block and clear:both can work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img {
    display: block; /* instead of float: left */
}
```

Don't complicate things by using `clear fix` or `overflow: hidden` to an unnecessary floating element later.

Comment: It should not be recommended because there's span element also can be anything there.

Comment: The key problem is with float, you may tell to the OP for using inline-block instead of float.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal sorry I didn't get you. what is the problem with span in a p tag?

Comment: I mean if there's some text using float is a choice, but OP has nothing to do with them(from the comment), so it's even better to just use display block as you're doing.